# Is it possible to have a pandas categorical column where each row can contain multiple categories?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to categorize the rows in my dataframe. Each row can belong to multiple categories.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['a, b', 'b, c, d', 'c'], 
    'B': [1, 2, 3]
})
```

If I do

```py
df['A'].astype('category')
Out[1]: 
0       a, b
1    b, c, d
2          c
Name: A, dtype: category
Categories (3, object): ['a, b', 'b, c, d', 'c']
```

It thinks the categories are the full strings. I'd like the categories to be a, b, c, and d.

P.S. I know I can do this by having separate columns `is_a`, `is_b` etc. but thought this solution may be easier/more scalable.

Comment: @Corralien I want the categories of the df above to be a, b, c, d. So, the first row would have categories a and b, the second b, c, and d and the third just c.

Comment: Ok but what do you want to do using category? Memory reduction, specific search, sort rows?

Comment: I'm going to use them to subset the df quickly e.g. get all rows that are category a

Answer (score 1):

Categories are unique per row, you cannot have multiple ones. Categories make sense to have custom values while allowing pandas to use underlying integers for efficiency.

Here are some alternatives that might be helpful.

Use a `set`:

```
df['A'].str.split(r',\s*').apply(set)

0       {a, b}
1    {d, c, b}
2          {c}
Name: A, dtype: object
```

Use [`dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html):

```
df['A'].str.get_dummies(sep=', ')

   a  b  c  d
0  1  1  0  0
1  0  1  1  1
2  0  0  1  0
```

Comment: The `get_dummies` method is a great idea!

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```
df = df.assign(A=df['A'].str.split(',')).explode('A')
df['A'].str.strip(' ').astype('category')
```

Output:

```
0    a
0    b
1    b
1    c
1    d
2    c
Name: A, dtype: category
Categories (4, object): ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Comment: Can you explain what the assign and explode methods do?

Comment: `assign` method creates or updates a column -- in my code, it updates column `A`. The method `split` will create a list per element of column A, each list containing the letters separately. Then the method `explode` converts each list into as many rows as the number of elements of the respective list, placing each letter in each row.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use the `str.contains` method to subset the df

```py
>>> df[df.A.str.contains('b')]
         A  B
0     a, b  1
1  b, c, d  2
```

Comment: But be careful with  `str.contains`, if you have categories with several letters, any substring would match. You could the use word boundaries `\b` to surround the query, but this won't work if you have words with spaces, etc. It's important to know to avoid pitfalls ;)